# Code obscuring in android studio

Tags: android-studio

If I click on a line with code on it in android studio, it highlights everything before my cursor in an opaque color that I can't read through.

I googled my question, and I found only things where people had accidentally hit the insert key.

I am using the `darcula` theme of android studio, but changing the theme doesn't help, it just highlights everything in black instead of white.

update: restarting android studio seemed to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exited android studio, didn't open it for a few days, and then today I opened it and the issue was gone.